# MS SQL SERVER 2005 express - Can't find import/export wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express, management-studio-express

I have installed ms sql 2005 express i have installed the management studio, i tried(all components already installed) to install the ms sql 2005 express toolkit.

I've searched for the .exe and for the option inside the management studio, and i simply can't find it!

Someone could help me please?
Maybe with an alternative way to export my db(i have to import it on another pc)?

Comment: Create a backup and then restore on the other machine.

Comment: i have no idea how (got some random errors) but i managed to get my db on the other pc. thx

Answer (score 0):

When you expand the list of databases, right-click on the database you need exported, and under `tasks` near the bottom are the `import data` and `export data` options (At least, this is the case in SSMS 2012):

[image]

However, as per my comment, if all you need to do is migrate a database, simply create a backup of the database, and restore it on the other machine.